# Foreground service is not working on Oreo (Android 8.1.0)

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I'm making an app that has two activities, of which one is the main activity. When the app starts, it creates a foreground service which registers a broadcast listener for USER_PRESENT intent. When the broadcast listener gets the broadcast, it triggers the second activity. I'm facing two problems with my code:
1) The foreground service notification does not come. However, the service runs.
2) The broadcast listener works fine when my app is the active app on the phone. But the broadcast listener doesn't work if my app is in the background. But the service is running because there are messages in the logs saying it was killed/stopped.

How to fix these two problems?

I am running the app on Oppo CPH1859 phone having Android 8.1.0

Android.manifest
+++++++++++++

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".MyFGService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>

    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

+++++

In main activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 Log.v("FIRST APP","Main activity started");
 myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyFGService.class);
 startService(myService);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopService(myService);
    Log.v("FIRST APP","Main activity destroyed");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

++++++++++++

In MyFGService

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service (re)starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.v("FIRST APP", "Service (re)starting");
    // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
    return START_STICKY;
}

private String createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "TEST Name";
        String description = "TEST Description";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel( "FirstAppNotifChannel", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        return channel.getId();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    Log.v("FIRST APP", "Service created");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    String notificationChannelID = createNotificationChannel();
    Log.v("FIRST APP","notification channel ID =" + notificationChannelID);
    Notification myNotification = new Notification.Builder(this, notificationChannelID)
                    .setContentTitle("TEST Title")
                    .setContentText("TEST Content")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build();

    startForeground(101, myNotification);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    registerReceiver(mReciever, filter);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.v("FIRST APP", "Service destroyed");
    unregisterReceiver(mReciever);
}
```